# Multiple trigger on same oscilloscope input

Tags: oscilloscope

Is there a risk to connect different signals to a single oscilloscope input (without using suming amplifier)?

In my case, I need to measure a signal that can be triggered by 2 different triggers, the problem is that I do not have any free oscilloscope channels. So it would be practical for me to connect 2 triggers on a single channel...

Comment: External trigger input on o-scope - do you have one?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a risk. that will almost certainly alter the behaviour of your circuit and may cause permanent damage, so don't do that.

One option could be to connect a 10M resistor to each signal and connect the other ends to your oscilloscope probe.

Answer (score 2):

In other word: you want to short both trigger sources together.

Why do you think this can **not** be a problem?

If the sources are low impedance voltage sources you need at least some rudimentary adding circuit (e.g. series resistors for each source).

If at least one of the trigger sources is floating (e.g. a secondary of a transformer) you could simply connect both trigger sources in series (but not in parall as you proposed).